# Access the file from salesforce

Tags: android, salesforce

I am using salesforce for my android app in backend.

and somewhere while using SOQL, I am getting response something like this :

```
Article_FileNames":"Template.doc"

Article_FileContentTypes":"application/msword

Article_FileBodys":"/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Hub_Knowledge_Articlekav/xxxxxxxxxxx/Article_FileBodys

ArticleNumber":"000001010

LastPublishedDate":"2015-12-09T20:34:48.000+0000
```

Now i am not getting, how I can let the user open the file named "Template.doc" on click.

How to open this file ?
is there any file path or id which will linkify this filename ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only file types that are *directly* available from outside of your Salesforce instance are images, which are made so by setting the `Externally Available Image` flag on the `Document` object itself.

If you need to work with other file types, you're going to have to build them yourself to facilitate their download by the end user. This can be done by querying your instance for the `Document`, which will contain the Base64 encoded file contents (`Body`), that array's length (`BodyLength`), the file extension (`Type`), and also the file name itself (`Name`).

Given what you provided, your SOQL query would look something like :

```
SELECT Body, BodyLength, Name, Type FROM Document WHERE Name = 'Template' AND Type = 'doc'
```

From there, you should have everything you need to build the file in memory.